# Add class based on checked checkbox

Tags: javascript

I am looking to simplify this code as it is to bulky for what it is doing. I do not need to stick to jQuery.

Simple checkbox in html relates to adding underline to some text:

```
$("#houseOrCar").on("change", function () {
    if ($(this).is(":checked") ) {
        $("#houseChosen").css("text-decoration", "none");
        $("#carChosen").css("text-decoration", "underline");
    } 
    else  {
        $("#houseChosen").css("text-decoration", "underline");
        $("#carChosen").css("text-decoration", "none");
    };
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a class that would only hold the property for the active element, in our case `text-decoration: underline;`. Then simply toggle each of the two labels to set on and off this "active" class (here called `underline`).
So you don't need to know which label is which, both will toggle anyway. Just set one of the two to have the class `.underline` on page load.

### Plain JavaScript

```js
const toggle = () => document.querySelectorAll('#labels > div')
  .forEach(label => label.classList.toggle('underline'))

document.querySelector('#houseOrCar').addEventListener('change', toggle);
```

```css
.underline {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="houseOrCar">

<div id="labels">
  <div class="underline">HOUSE</div>
  <div>CAR</div>
</div>
```

Note I'm using the [`.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) method of the [`nodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) class:

> The forEach() method of the NodeList interface calls the callback given in parameter once for each value pair in the list, in insertion order.

---

### jQuery

And here it is implemented with jQuery, which is shorter but very similar:

```js
const toggle = () => $('#labels > div')
  .each((i,e) => $(e).toggleClass('underline'));

$('#houseOrCar').on('change', toggle);
```

```css
.underline {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="houseOrCar">

<div id="labels">
  <div class="underline">HOUSE</div>
  <div>CAR</div>
</div>
```

It's not worth using jQuery for this, personally, I would stick with the plain version. However, if you happen to already use jQuery in your project then go for it!